Seeking Feedback on Rejection
I currently live in a big city but grew up in a small town that has only one company in my niche field. Unfortunately, there aren’t any other options in the entire state. I’d love to move back home for several personal reasons, including my aging parents who can no longer travel, and my wife and I are feeling worn out by city life.
The good news is that the company is expanding and hiring. With my background (PhD + 15YOE), I believe I’m an ideal candidate, and I doubt they attract many applicants with my level of expertise.
I thought this position was a sure thing. The recruiter seemed enthusiastic about my application and mentioned multiple openings that would suit me.
However, after receiving positive feedback, I was surprised to get a rejection just two weeks later. I wonder if they considered me too expensive given my city salary, but I’m open to a pay cut. Unfortunately, I didn’t get a chance to discuss this or address any concerns.
I’ve tried reaching out to the recruiter for clarification but she simply ghosted me. I also couldn’t identify the hiring manager in any network. The positions still seem to be open, and I doubt they would post jobs that don’t exist.
So, my question is: is there anything I can do? I know pursuing rejections are mostly unproductive, but these circumstances offer a unique opportunity for me to return home.

Sounds like "keep looking", you can't force them...

"I doubt they would post jobs that don't exist" - Sadly, that is a fairly recent phenomenon, IIRC due to Tax breaks for vacant positions. If they have said No and you cannot talk with anyone - best you move on.

"With my background (PhD + 15 YOE),...". Does this mean you could be overqualified for the jobs ? -- If the job title says "Looking for a senior engineer with 8 YOE", and you have "a PhD + 15 YOE", they may give you positive feedback regarding your application, but may not bother to interview you.  Please make sure you apply for the right jobs.

@Job_September_2020 may have a point. If PhD is typically a person focused on academic research. If that isn't with the company is looking for, they may take that as a sign that you are going to want to be paid more than they want to pay for the job they want done, and/or that you will be bored and unmotivated by the job. You may want to put more emphasis on the experience and less on the degree, and you may want to make sure you are applying for jobs where they are expecting somebody with 15 years of experience.

wonder if they considered me too expensive given my city salary Did you tell them, you were open to a pay cut? Were you the first do name a salary?

Wait 6 months and apply again - even if they aren't hiring

You are right that generally, "pursuing rejections are mostly unproductive". It's probably time to move on as other people have said.

However, there may be one last angle to look at in your situation.
This is a small town. So, it seems many people would know one another personally. Is it right ?
So, do you or your family happen to know someone who is currently working for that company (such as a childhood friend, high school friend, former neighbor, etc...) ?
If yes, maybe, you could contact that person to ask how you can apply for the jobs based on that personal connection (networking).
That person could be your good reference, and he/she could tell you who to talk to in the company to get your application to the right hiring manager.
It may work out more effectively that way.
It could be that previously, when you first applied for the jobs, no one in that company really knew that you grew up in that small town, and your family have had a connection to that town, and now you want to move back to the old town.

"Its not what you know but who you know that matters." Especially for small buisnesses in a small town.


Is there anything I can do?

Sure, there's stuff you can try:

Phone the front desk of the company and try and get to talk to someone.
Write them an actual, physical letter.
Turn up at their office.

Will any of those get you feedback? Probably not. Will any of those get you the job? Almost certainly not. I understand this job is important to you, but putting it bluntly, the company doesn't care about you and your needs.


grew up in a small town that has only one company in my niche field

You and I are very alike. except of course I decided to start my career in the small town my parents live in rather than trying to end my career there.

I wonder if they considered me too expensive given my city salary

It is possible, or they looked at where you have lived for the past 15 years and thought... "This person has lived inside of a big cities for the past 15 years. Once he realizes that we are a small little town, he (or his wife) are going to turn down this position because we are located in the middle of nowhere. So they are saving themselves money by not interviewing someone who seems to prefer living in the big city. Alternatively, if that big city that you lived in was located in California, they might just dislike Californians and the culture that Californians insist on exporting from their trash fire of a state.
What to do?
This is a small company in a small town. It's not what you know, but who you know that matters. My personnel recommendation is to reach out to a family friend that works for this company and express your interest in returning home to take of your folks and ask them if they would be willing to recommend you for a job there.
Where I work, employee recommendations are guaranteed to get an interview for a job, regardless of how they look on paper. And this is true for most small businesses which tend to rely on personal connections to find new employees over casting a hook in the sea and hoping that they get a lucky bite.

If you have the guts to try go for it. But it is rough.
You have nothing to lose - As long as you don't act repugnant and burn bridges.
Recruiters are a layer between you and the opportunity. If the recruiter ghosted you, go direct to the company.
Put yourself out there, literally knock on doors.
Message via linkedin. Politely - asking for an opportunity to speak with someone about your abilities and what you have to offer company X.
Be polite at all times. Go over and around those that say no.
You are selling yourself to this company.
Expect a lot of "No" answers, but you only need one "Yes".
It is a long shot and can be disappointing, but if you don't try how will you know? There is no easy answer.

Wow, it looks things are going to become really s...uboptimal, in the answer voting.

@GraySheep we are getting pummeled, but with no feedback. It is odd.

I think we have a voting circle or a botnet voter.

Note that there is only very few new questions since a while. Maybe there is some connection among them? Looks this site is dying.

Oh, the dream job with the exact match! You can not even imagine, how could have they been so... both evil and braindamaged.
Yes.
Bosses, companies are working so. Don't hope, you won't ever know, why they did it.
Most importantly,
Until you don't have a clear offer, you don't have the job. Positive feedback of the "recruiter" is nothing. (Particularly if the recruiter himself is not even employee of the company - such "intermediaries" are only fraudulent spammers posing as same personal decision maker.)
Positive feedback of the boss is nothing.
If you have a clean offer of the boss, that is already something. You really have the job if you have the signed contract in your hands.
There is no such thing that you are an exact match so you should be accepted. It is their decision and... very often... companies are so evil.
You can not control induvidual companies, you can control chances. Do not hope that you will get a specific dream job. Do not think that you will be hired because you are so good. Particularly if you are in the USA. The boss decides, to whom he wants to give his money, you won't ever know, why he decided it. It might have been any the most nasty reason, it might have been some cold rationality, or it might have been that he has simply overlooked.
What can not be: not all company can be so... sub-optimal to all applicants. So the economy could not work.
Wait a half year and apply again.

I did not downvote your answer and I do believe it does not definitely deserve a -7 score but I can sense why people might not have agreed. Your last paragraph, slightly echos as preaching. Again, I am not saying it's completely out of the question's context, but it doesn't really address OP's concerns.

I think a lot of the downvotes are due to bad grammar.

@Questor I think, not. While my grammar has some... uhmm.. room for improvement :-), normally the downs and the other actions (comments & edit suggestions) have a much more pleasant ratio. So many silent downs, I just don't believe. I think it is much more like a revenge action for something, of course the company/moderation ignores this whole thing et al.

@GraySheep There is no simple edit to fix your answer, I don't am not sure what you were saying 50% of the time, and I am guessing the other 50%. I think I understand the intent of your answer, but with how garbled this is... I could be completely wrong.

The other major problem is that you are describing this in terms of good and evil. The company is not evil. They are picking the person who they think best meets their needs, according to complex criteria. If they don't think you are the candidate that they are looking for, that is no more evil than somebody deciding that you are not the boyfriend or girlfriend they are looking for.  You usually don't get detailed feedback in that situation either. All you can do is accept it, move on to the next opportunity, and maybe ask them again next time both you and they are looking for a match.
